# Exporting from SQL Server to Excel file and store in another server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, bcp, sqlcmd

I have my SQL Server database on one server and my web application on another server (ASP.NET MVC). I would like to generate some reports (basically just a stored procedure / select a view) and store it in the drive of my web application, all automated.

I am able to generate the reports on my local computer using SQLCMD/BCP right now, but what are the recommendations / possible options if I want it generated to another server?

Comment: if your local computer has an access to the other server, then you automate the job and make it copy the file to a shared folder on the web server

Comment: Any instructions on how I can allow access to my app server? Do I have to set up FTP and all that stuff?

Comment: You can create a folder in your web server, right click and select Share With, then select a speceific user that you will use to connect to the web service, this will make the folder shareable and you can type the server name followed by the folder name, ex: if the folder name is Reports, and your server name is webappsrv, the path will be: \\webappsrv\Reports
Make sure the user has a write access to this folder when you share it

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you can share folders that way only if they are under the same domain right? That wouldn't really work for me because my database server and app server are two different servers.

Comment: It is not a mandatory to be on the same domain, the only thing is that they should be on the same network

Comment: I'll explore more on this, thanks!